# reading a file and storing it contents into a list

Tags: java, file

I have the following file named ght.txt in my c: and it contains the following data

```
Id|ytr|yts
1|W|T
2|W|T
3|W|T
```

Now the thing is that positions of this columns (Id|ytr|yts) is also not in order means they can be resuffled also..for ex

```
Id|ytr|dgfj|fhfjk|fgrt|yts
```

now please advise how can I read this txt file through java and display it contents on the console.
what I want to achieve is  to read the first row and create a List that indicates the headers included and their order.Then,  read the remaining lines, one at a time, and then split the string into parts. You can then use the header list you created from the first line to determine what each of the parts are. please advise how to achieve this

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are defining what you want to do and asking how to do what you have just defined how to do.

Comment: As the downvote button tooltip say: This question does not show any research effort...

Answer (score 1):

for such situations its better to use `csv` files. you can parse it like a table. there are third party libraries for java; as an example [Opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

File: sample.csv

```
COUNTRY,CAPITAL,POPULATION
India,New Delhi, 1.21B
People's republic of China,Beijing, 1.34B
United States,Washington D.C., 0.31B
```

Reading  CSV file line by line:

```
String csvFilename = "path/to/sample.csv";
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
String[] row = null;
while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
    System.out.println(row[0]
              + " # " + row[1]
              + " #  " + row[2]);
}
//...
csvReader.close();
```

you can read more in details [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/).